# How to synchronize changes to modules across DolphinDB cluster nodes?

Tags: module, dolphindb

I made some changes to the functions in a custom module located in the server/modules directory, but the modifications were not automatically synchronized to other nodes in the cluster.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the modifications applied to all nodes in the DolphinDB cluster, you have two options:

1. Use GUI to connect to each node and manually synchronize the
   modified module files to the server on each node.

[image]

**Note:**  The modified files are uploaded to the homeDir/modules directory of each node by default.

2. Navigate to homeDir/modules directory of each node and modify the
   specific files.

DolphinDB's modules are used for node-level management, so modifications on one node will not be automatically synchronized to other nodes. On the other hand, the function views are used for cluster-wide management, ensuring consistent changes across the entire cluster.